# SQLite in iOS sqlite3_exec fails

Tags: ios, sqlite

I have the code:

```
if (sqlite3_open([dbPath UTF8String], &db) == SQLITE_OK)
    {
        const char *sql_stmt = "create table contacts (id integer primary key autoincrement, name text, address text, phone text);";

        if (sqlite3_exec(db, sql_stmt, NULL, NULL, NULL) == SQLITE_OK)
        {
            av = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"Success!!!" message:nil delegate:nil cancelButtonTitle:@"OK" otherButtonTitles:nil];
        }
        else
        {
            av = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"Error3" message:nil delegate:nil cancelButtonTitle:@"OK" otherButtonTitles:nil];
        }
} else {
        av = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"Error2" message:nil delegate:nil cancelButtonTitle:@"OK" otherButtonTitles:nil];
    }
```

I get to sqlite3_exec but it returns exit code 26: File opened that is not a database file. Why would the if statement execute though if that was the case though?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: You should start by finding out what sqlite3_exec actually returns.

Comment: I do believe that sqlite3_exec returns false if your query fails...but I don't know why that would be, works perfectly fine in terminal.

Comment: Take a look at [this](http://www.sqlite.org/c3ref/c_abort.html)

Comment: Use the fifth parameter of `sqlite3_exec` to return the error message. Or perhaps inquire with `sqlite3_errmsg` and see what it reports. Perhaps the table already exists? Perhaps `create table if not exists contacts ...`

Comment: So I'm getting error code 26, "File opened that is not a database file" but then why is the first if statement returning true. I'll edit my question to show more code.

Comment: That's because sqlite does lazy opening of files; it won't discover that the file isn't a real database until you run a query on it.